# Copy files without directories in bash script

Tags: bash, scripts, rsync

I'm trying to write a script that runs on startup and copies any files on any attached USB drive to a specific directory but without the containing directories.

So i have a USB drive called Data, on data there is a 2 directories, Dir1 & Dir2, in each directory there is a file. Dir1File.txt and Dir2File.txt.

I want to copy the two files to /home/data but if i run

```
rsync -av /media/* /home/data
```

data then has a directory called Data, inside which are Dir1 & Dir 2 inside which are the respective files. Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `find` command to get a list of all files and then use a loop to copy the files one by one. Something like this:

```
for i in `find /media -type f` ; do cp $i /home/data/ ; done
```

Of course, if the same filename appears in several places then that file will be overwritten and you will just get the last one.

Edit: it is probably better to do the copying already as part of the find command instead of using a loop, as described in the comment by steeldriver below.

Comment: `find /media -type f -exec cp -t /home/data/ {} +` would likely be more efficient - and wouldn't error out on any filenames with spaces in them. See [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697/why-is-looping-over-finds-output-bad-practice). You can add `-n` (`--no-clobber`) or `--backup=numbered` to `cp` if you want to avoid overwriting existing files.